# Count only one value for one ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having two columns: first contains values (in this case hours) and the second contains IDs. I need to sum just one value for one ID. I'm not sure if it is clear, but "solution" of this example should be **19,5**

Unfortunately, this table is not prepared in some nice design, so I can't even use pivot table.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

[image: screenshot here]

Comment: Didn't check screenshot but guessing `sumif`.

Comment: Given your example in the screenshot, what results are you expecting?

Comment: he is expecting 19,5 which is 3 x 6,5.  unfortunately there are 2-5s, 2-4s, and 1-1.  there is not three of anything.  so not sure how they want to get to 19,5 based on the presented data

Comment: In this case 19,5because there are 3 different IDs.

Comment: AHHH you you want to generate a list of unique IDs and sum there values.

Comment: Will the value associate with a an ID always be the same for that id?  ie will all ID 5s have a value of 6.5?

Comment: Not really. I just need to get value "19,5". For example: Values are workers and ID is production line. It is not the right situation, but this will suffice.. So i need 19,5 workers (x,5 is there for another reason, i should have posted better image) to cover one shift. I hope it's far more clear now.

Comment: my concern was that you did not have di not have a value of 4 and an id of 5 in one row and then in another row sometime later you had a value of 6,5 and an id of 5.  because in that situation we would need to know which value for 5 to use sine they are not the same.

Comment: I saw the post about function using sum, if and frequency and it works perfectly    --  =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(G2:G6,G2:G6)>0,C2:C6))      -- or should i expect some troubles in the future?

Comment: I saw it briefly as well, and I am not sure why they erased it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I have uses a helper column.  It assumes your values are column A and your IDs are column B.

In the column adjacent to IDs use the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)
```

Then in the cell where you want your answer use the following SUMIF formula

```
=SUMIF(C2:C6,1,A2:A6)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that may work would be to use an array formula:

```
{=SUM((A1:A5)/COUNTIF(B1:B6,B1:B6))}
```

This will divide every entry in column A by the count of the number of IDs before summing.

```
6,5    5    = 3,25
6,5    5    = 3,25
6,5    4    = 3,25
6,5    4    = 3,25
6,5    1    = 6,5
             ------
              19,5
```

In order to enter the formula as an array, do not type the {'s. Instead, use CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER when complete.